# ZF2 Catching Exceptions doesn't work

Tags: php, email, exception, zend-framework2

I wrote service to sending emails in ZF2 and unfortunatelly sometimes I get exception:

```
Zend\Mail\Protocol\Exception\RuntimeException
Could not read from [smtp server]
```

Part of stack trace:

```
#0 /homez.157/pastydol/www/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/AbstractProtocol.php(339): Zend\Mail\Protocol\AbstractProtocol->_receive(300)
#1 /homez.157/pastydol/www/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(353): Zend\Mail\Protocol\AbstractProtocol->_expect(221, 300)
#2 /homez.157/pastydol/www/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(389): Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp->quit()
#3 /homez.157/pastydol/www/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(380): Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp->_disconnect()
#4 /homez.157/pastydol/www/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(152): Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp->disconnect()
#5 /homez.157/pastydol/www/module/Page/src/Page/Controller/OrderController.php(144): Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp->__destruct()
```

I want to catch this exception, in service, which sending email I did:

```
try {
    $transport->send($mail);
} catch(\Zend\Mail\Exception $e) {
    return -1;
}
catch(\Exception $ex) {
    return -1;
}
```

But it doesn't work, I still getting these exceptions.

Comment: It says it is occurring on line 144 of your OrderController, is that line visible in the code you linked above?

Comment: In this line (144 of OrderController) I call the function of my mail service, where I used try..catch as above.